# Downloading image from url in Ruby and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to download an image from url in ruby and rails, so far what I have done is

```
require 'base64'
        parsedUri = URI.parse('http://somewebsite.com/path/to/image.jpeg')
        http = Net::HTTP.new(parsedUri.host, parsedUri.port)
        if params[:src].include? "https"
            http.use_ssl = true 
        end
        request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(parsedUri.request_uri, {'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0'})
        response = http.request(request)
        image = Base64.encode64(response.body)
        File.open('some.jpeg', "w+") do |f|
          f.write(image)
        end
```

,
Now this code does make a file in my root directory but when I open it, it given me error "Error interpreting JPEG image file (Not a JPEG file: starts with 0x64 0x61)" the irony is when I open that file in gedit and use the same base64 encoded to render image in browser using img tag. The image gets rendered. I am using Ubuntu. Please help it is driving me nuts

Comment: I see no need to call `Base.encode`. Did you try it without that? Just `image = response.body`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for the `Base64.encode64` part. I removed that and restructured the code a bit:

```
uri  = URI.parse('http://somewebsite.com/path/to/image.jpeg')
http = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
http.use_ssl = params[:src].include?('https')

response = http.request(
  Net::HTTP::Get.new(uri.request_uri, {
    'User-Agent' => 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0'
  })
)

File.open('some.jpeg', 'wb') { |f| f.write(response.body) }
```

Comment: true @spickermann said same thing. Also I needed to change the mode from 'w+' to 'wb' because of exception encoding error from ascii to utf-8

Comment: Can you please accept that answer if it solve your question. Otherwiese it will stay on the list of unsolved questions. Btw: I am spickermann...